# Must be one SQL statement, must get event, sale and attendee count per waiter-month but not use iteration

Tags: mysql, sql, iteration

It seems like I can either count sales and events ("COUNT(DISTINCT event) as SaleCount" in the event-sale join temp table)  in a waiter-month or count the number of event attendees served in a waiter-month (in the event table), but not both in the same SQL statement unless I use iteration (which I am trying to avoid as I am scared of the loop overhead)

Events table

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  `event` INTEGER,
  `month` VARCHAR(3),
  `attendees` INTEGER,
  `waiter` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO 
events
  (`event`, `month`, `attendees`, `waiter`) VALUES
  ('1', 'jan', '5', 'bob'),
  ('2', 'feb', '2', 'bob'),
  ('3', 'feb', '1', 'bob'),
  ('4', 'feb', '2', 'sally');
```

Sales table

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  `sale` INTEGER,
  `event` INTEGER,
  `profit` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO 
sales
  (`sale`, `event`, `profit`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '10'),
  ('2', '1', '20'),
  ('3', '1', '15'),
  ('4', '2', '25'),
  ('5', '2', '5'),
  ('6', '2', '30'),
  ('7', '3', '25'),
  ('8', '3', '5'),
  ('9', '3', '30'),
  ('10', '4', '25'),
  ('11', '4', '5'),
  ('12', '4', '30');
```

Event-Sales join temp table

```
sale    event   month   attendees   profit ($)  waiter
1       1       jan     5           10  bob
2       1       jan     5           20  bob
3       1       jan     5           15  bob
4       2       feb     2           25  bob
5       2       feb     2           5   bob
6       2       feb     2           30  bob
7       3       feb     1           25  bob
8       3       feb     1           5   bob
9       3       feb     1           30  bob
10      4       feb     2           25  sally
11      4       feb     2           5   sally
12      4       feb     2           30  sally
```

Required output

Productivity for month

```
waiter-month    attendees   events  sales
bob-jan         5           1       3
bob-feb         3           2       6
sally-feb       2           1       3
```

Edit:
Above I only now added "waiter", "waiter-month" and replaced sale count with event count as i forgot this is in fact the requirement

Comment: Please tag your database and show us desired output for the sample data above

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: If you have a new requirement post another question and don't change this because by doing it you invalidate all the answers that you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible to join 2 sub-queries.

> ```
> select 
>  concat(qe.waiter,'-',qe.month) as `waiter-month`
> , qe.attendees
> , qe.events
> , qs.sales
> from 
> (
>   select e.waiter, e.month
>   , month(str_to_date(e.month,'%b')) as monthNr
>   , sum(attendees) as attendees
>   , count(*) as events
>   from events e
>   group by e.month, e.waiter
> ) qe
> left join
> (
>   select e.month, e.waiter
>   , sum(s.profit) as profits
>   , count(s.sale) as sales
>   from events e
>   join sales s 
>     on s.event = e.event
>   group by e.month, e.waiter
> ) qs 
>  on qs.month = qe.month
> and qs.waiter = qe.waiter
> order by qe.waiter, qe.monthNr
> ```
>
> ```
> waiter-month | attendees | events | sales
> :----------- | --------: | -----: | ----:
> bob-jan      |         5 |      1 |     3
> bob-feb      |         3 |      2 |     6
> sally-feb    |         2 |      1 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bab2a635038f287323c8f25bd6127fbc)*

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a straightforward `GROUP BY` using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT 
    e.event as EventId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.sales) as SaleCount,
    SUM(e.attendees) as TotalAttendees
FROM event e
JOIN sales s
ON e.event = s.event
GROUP BY e.event
```

Comment: this results in jan having 15 attendees which is false as there were only 5

Comment: @TechnoloJesus - There is no month in this query.  It groups by `event` - If this isn't what you need, you'll have to add expected output to your question.

Comment: More pain in translating that then asking a question that is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by event, month`:

```
select 
  s.event, e.month, 
  max(e.attendees) attendees, 
  count(s.profit) sales
from sales s inner join events e
on e.event = s.event
group by s.event, e.month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5ff86e71a8e990c3c3d0e15765ac2683).
Results:

```
> event | month | attendees | sales
> ----: | :---- | --------: | ----:
>     1 | jan   |         5 |     3
>     2 | feb   |         2 |     3
```

Or `group by month` only:

```
select 
  e.month, 
  max(e.attendees) attendees, 
  count(s.profit) sales
from sales s inner join events e
on e.event = s.event
group by e.month
```